# vue create not working when creating new project in cmd

Tags: vue.js, cmd

i have installed the vue/cli by using npm but when i write vue create noting is loading

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFVOk.png

Comment: what do you get when you do "vue --version" ?

Comment: the version is 4.1.2

Comment: when you did "vue create client" can you show the error message.

Comment: there's no error that's the problem its just loading

Comment: what is your node version?

Comment: the version is v11.10.0

Comment: Please, copy and paste the script output rather than adding a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue this morning. Same version (4.1.2).

I disconnected from the internet/network, tried again and it worked 100%. It seems like its waiting for a network request to respond (which never does). Hope this helps.