# Vue create doesn't work - No output from console or Vue UI

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, windows-11

As the title states. I can not get the Vue CLI to work. I've tried `vue create hello-world`. This returns no output. I've also tried `vue ui` which returns   `Starting GUI...` but nothing else.
I've tried.
[vue create not working when creating new project in cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59869523/vue-create-not-working-when-creating-new-project-in-cmd)
along with countless others. Clearing npm cache. Setting npm proxy to null then false.
Disconnecting from the internet and running the following commands:

```
npm uninstall -g vue
npm uninstall -g vue-cli
npm uninstall -g @vue/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g vue
npm install -g @vue/cli
npm audit fix --force
```

In almost all of the other issues. They get some output to the command line. I can not get anything.

```
Specs 
Windows 11 20H2 Build 22000.739
NodeJs ver: 16.13.2
Vue Cli: Latest
```

Comment: The cli may stall, because of a missing proxy configuration. The program does not seem to use the standard `http_proxy` environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure node latest version is installed in your machine.

```
node -v
```

Then, Download vue from npm registry

```
npm init vue@latest
```

Check out [Official Docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#with-build-tools) for more information.

Comment: How does that solve their problem?

Comment: This doesnt fix the whole problem but it does serve as a work around. Thank you. I am able to get the project off the ground. I am still curious as to why the following 
`
npm install -g @vue/cli
vue create
`
Doesnt work as stated in the Vue CLI Docs https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

downgrade from your node version to version 16, I was have the same issue but I solve it with this way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).